# Delete custom post type and redirect to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using `get_delete_post_link` to delete custom post from the front-end, but after deletion I get 404 page. How can I redirect to homepage after custom post is deleted?

I inserted in functions.php this code:

```
function wp_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete Post', $before = '', $after = '') {
    global $post;
    $link = "<a href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . 
    $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'>".$link."</a>";
    echo $before . $link . $after;
}
```

And after that I created shortcode to generate delete button:

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode( $atts ) {
    wp_delete_post_link();
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

Is there a way to improve this code to achieve redirection after deletion?

Comment: I don't know wordpress, but maybe you can: 1)  use PHP `sleep()` function, while showing an helpful message; 2) send a <script> with at least `window.location.href = ...`

Comment: Hi pierpy, thanks for the suggestion, but php and wp backed aren't my my strong suit, so I'm not sure what to do with this advice. In any case, I find a solution through 404 redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many code snippets for redirecting after deletion a custom post, but none of them worked. So I tried another approach: to redirect 404 page to custom frontend editor dashboard which I built for the Editor role user. Here's the code:

```
function editor_redirect_404() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) );
      exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'editor_redirect_404', 1);
```

I don't want the visitors of the site to experience this (they have regular 404 page), so this redirection is applied only if user is logged in and have the Editor role. This is achieved by using condition builder in WPCodeBox plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * template_redirect Action Hook.
 * Redirect users to home page
 * after deleting a custom post type post.
 */
function redirect_on_delete() {
    // Custom post type plural name or rewrite slug name.
    $custom_post_type = 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE';

    $regex = "/" . $custom_post_type . ".*" . preg_quote(  "/?deleted=", "/" ) . "\d+" . "/i";

    if ( preg_match( $regex, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ) ) {
        \nocache_headers();
        if ( \wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( get_home_url() ) ) ) {
            exit;
        };
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_on_delete', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this code, like many others that I tried, isn't working for me. But I found other solution which does.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Could you please mark your solution as the accepted answer? That way, when the question appears in search results of future visitors it will be clear an answer was found. Thanks.